# change color according to the axis, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, colors

[image: graph]

In this graph I would like to make everything negative in x to be red, and in y to be green, or just the 3 most negative dots be red and 3 most positive dots be green.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ex_x = [res1,res2,res3,res4,res5,res6,res7,res8,res9,res10,res11,res12,res13,res14,res15,res16,res17,res18,res19,res20,res21,res22,res23,res24,res25,res26,res27,res28,res29,res30,res31,res32,res33,res34,res35,res36,res37,res38,res39,res40,res41,res42,res43,res44,res45,res46,res47]
ex_y = ["1","2","2.1","2.1.1","2.2","3","3.1","3.2","4","4.1","4.1.1","4.1.1A)","4.1.1B)","4.1.2","4.2","4.2A)","4.2B)","4.3","4.4","5","5.1","5.1.1","5.1.2","5.1.2A)","5.1.2B)","5.1.3","5.1.4","5.2","5.2.1","5.2.1A)","5.2.1B)","5.2.1C)","5.2.2","5.2.3","5.2.3A)","5.2.3B)","5.2.4","5.2.5","6","6.1","7","7.1","7.2","8.1","8.1A)","8.1B)","8.2"]

l_x = [0, 0]
l_y = [47, 0]

z_x = [-10, 10]
z_y = [0, 0]

plt.grid(True)

for x in range(-10,10):
    plt.plot(l_x, l_y, color = "k", linewidth = 2)

plt.plot(z_x, z_y, color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
plt.plot(ex_x, ex_y, marker='.')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.title("Perfil Neuropsicológico")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to transform the lists ex_x and ex_y to numpy arrays as a first step:

```py
import numpy as np
ex_x = np.array(ex_x)
ex_y = np.array(ex_y)
```

As a second step, the selection of only positive or negative values is pretty straightforward:

```py
plt.plot(ex_x[ex_x<0], ex_y[ex_x<0], color='red', marker='.', linestyle='none')
plt.plot(ex_x[ex_x>=0], ex_y[ex_x>=0], color='green', marker='.', linestyle='none')
```

This is one of the perks of numpy arrays!

As you see, I have removed the connecting lines in this example. Having those would be more involved (what would the color of a line between a red and a green dot be?). What you could do, of course, is plot an additional line with all the data in a neutral color, e.g.

```py
plt.plot(ex_x, ex_y, color='dimgrey')
```

It would be easiest, then, to keep this line in the background by plotting it "before" the other points.

---

On a side note: I think in the `for` loop, you plot the same line 20 times.

Comment: thanks, it worked just like I wanted, will look more into numpy arrays because that is something I don't know  much about, again, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
# make some test data (np.ndarray types)
y = np.random.random(100)-0.5
x = np.arange(len(y))

plt.plot( x, y)
plt.plot( x[y<0], y[y<0], 'r.') # color negative red
plt.plot( x[y>=0], y[y>=0], 'g.')
order = np.argsort(y)  # order of y sorted from lowest to highest
plt.plot( x[order[:3]], y[order[:3]], 'rs', ms=10, mfc='none')  # lowest 3
plt.plot( x[order[-3:]], y[order[-3:]], 'gs', ms=10, mfc='none')  # highest 3
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: the square was a nice add up into my project, thanks, also I changed argsort to x axis because I was working on it, thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers already here are great - I just want to add a method to have the lines (not just the points) red or green depending on `+x` or `-x` side.

Unfortunately, there are no easy methods to just change the color of a line midpoint in matplotlib, the trick is to 'break up' the line so you can color each segment. In your case, the trick is to add some 'fake' points at `x = 0` so you can color the line `-x` to `x = 0` red and the line `x = 0` to `+x` in green. A quick illustration of the 'fake' point and the line segmentation that we want to accomplish:

[image: A quick illustration]

Here is a stab at it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex_y = ["1", "2", "2.1", "2.1.1", "2.2", "3", "3.1", "3.2", "4", "4.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.1A)", "4.1.1B)", "4.1.2",
            "4.2", "4.2A)", "4.2B)", "4.3", "4.4", "5", "5.1", "5.1.1", "5.1.2", "5.1.2A)", "5.1.2B)", "5.1.3", "5.1.4",
            "5.2", "5.2.1", "5.2.1A)", "5.2.1B)", "5.2.1C)", "5.2.2", "5.2.3", "5.2.3A)", "5.2.3B)", "5.2.4", "5.2.5",
            "6", "6.1", "7", "7.1", "7.2", "8.1", "8.1A)", "8.1B)", "8.2"]

    # Make some fake data
    # Fixing random state for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(19680801)
    # Random data arrays the size of ex_y
    ex_x = list(np.random.randn(len(ex_y)))
    # Make a y-axis based on numbers so we can manipulate it later (ex_y we can use to set the y-tick labels later)
    numerical_y = list(np.arange(0, len(ex_y), 1))

    l_x = [0, 0]
    l_y = [47, 0]

    z_x = [-10, 10]
    z_y = [0, 0]
```

Now that we have all the set-up done, we can start looking into making the 'fake' points. The trick is to A) find between what points it goes from `-x` to `+x` and insert a fake point, and B) find the y-value of the fake point at `x = 0` (aka the y-intercept).

Let's start with B. We need the 'x' and 'y' value of our 'fake' point - we already have 'x' (x=0) but we need the 'y' value (the y-intercept).  We can use the equation of a line (`y = m*x + c` where `m` is the slope and `c` is a constant) to find the y-intercept. We can define a function such as `find_y_intercept` to find the y value between two points:

```
def find_y_intercept(point_1, point_2) -> float:
    """
    Find y-intercept
    :param point_1: (x1, y1)
    :param point_2: (x2, y2)
    :return:
    """
    x1, y1 = point_1
    x2, y2 = point_2

    # Equation of a line is y = m * x + c, where m is the slope, c is a constant, and x/y are the variables.
    # First, find slope m using x and y values of points 1 and 2
    m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
    # Next, find constant c using one point (in this case point 1) and the slope m we just calculated, plug m and the point into the line equation
    c = y1 - m * x1
    # Now, plug x = 0 into the line equation to find the y intercept
    y_intercept = m * 0 + c
    return y_intercept
```

Now we have a method to calculate what value y will be when `x = 0`, so we have the x (x=0) and y (y-intercept) values of our 'fake' point.

The next step is to find between what points it goes from `-x` to `+x`, and insert the 'fake' point in between those key points. To accomplish this we can compare each point in `ex_x` to the previous point and see if the sign changed - if it did, then add the new 'fake' point with x=0 and the y-intercept value using `find_y_intercept` we just defined.

```
    for idx_point, x_point in enumerate(ex_x):
        # Skip the first value as we need 2 points for a line
        if idx_point == 0:
            continue
        # Get the x and y value of the point before so we can compare it with the current point to see if it crossed the x-axis
        x_point_before = ex_x[idx_point-1]
        y_point = numerical_y[idx_point]
        y_point_before = numerical_y[idx_point-1]
        # We are looking for when x goes from positive to negative and vice-versa
        if ((x_point < 0) == (x_point_before < 0)) == False:
            # If they are 0.0, we already introduced the 'fake' point so we can skip
            if x_point_before == 0.0 or x_point == 0.0:
                continue
            # The point before
            point_1 = (x_point_before, y_point_before)
            # The current point
            point_2 = (x_point, y_point)
            # Find y value
            y_intercept = find_y_intercept(point_1, point_2)
            # Insert new fake x and y points into our data
            numerical_y.insert(idx_point, y_intercept)
            ex_x.insert(idx_point, 0.0)
```

Okay, now we have inserted the 'fake' points into our x and y data arrays. We are almost done!

The next step is to put all the lines (between each point in the data) in a matplotlib [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection). We could have a `for` loop plotting each line and writing some logic to color the line red or green depending on the x-values of the points. However, `LineCollection` is more efficient than plotting each line (this is key in large datasets). So to make a `LineCollection` we need to create segments (loosely based on [this LineCollection example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)) and color each segment accordingly.

```
    # Create a set of line segments so that we can color them individually
    # This creates the points as a N x 1 x 2 array so that we can stack points
    # together easily to get the segments. The segments array for line collection
    # needs to be numlines x points per line x 2 (x and y)
    points = np.array([ex_x, numerical_y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

    # What color each line segment will be
    linecolors = []
    for line in segments:
        # Check what the combined x value of endpoints of the line would be
        value = line[0][0] + line[1][0]
        # if both endpoints are negative, then that line is red
        color_line = 'r' if value < 0 else 'g'
        linecolors.append(color_line)

    # Create the line collection object, setting the colormapping parameters.
    # Have to set the actual values used for colormapping separately.
    lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=linecolors)
    lc.set_array(ex_x)
```

And now we can plot our `LineCollection`:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(ex_y), 1))
    ax.set_yticklabels(ex_y)
    for x in range(-10, 10):
        plt.plot(l_x, l_y, color="k", linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(z_x, z_y, color='k', linewidth=1)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.title("Perfil Neuropsicológico")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

[image: final_fig]

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Here is the code, unbroken, so you can have a working copy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


def find_y_intercept(point_1, point_2) -> float:
    """
    Find y-intercept
    :param point_1: (x1, y1)
    :param point_2: (x2, y2)
    :return:
    """
    x1, y1 = point_1
    x2, y2 = point_2

    # Equation of a line is y = m * x + c, where m is the slope and c is a constant
    # Find slope me using point 1 and 2
    m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
    # Find constant using one point and the slope m in the line equation
    c = y1 - m * x1
    # x = 0 for y intercept
    y_intercept = m * 0 + c
    return y_intercept


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex_y = ["1", "2", "2.1", "2.1.1", "2.2", "3", "3.1", "3.2", "4", "4.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.1A)", "4.1.1B)", "4.1.2",
            "4.2", "4.2A)", "4.2B)", "4.3", "4.4", "5", "5.1", "5.1.1", "5.1.2", "5.1.2A)", "5.1.2B)", "5.1.3", "5.1.4",
            "5.2", "5.2.1", "5.2.1A)", "5.2.1B)", "5.2.1C)", "5.2.2", "5.2.3", "5.2.3A)", "5.2.3B)", "5.2.4", "5.2.5",
            "6", "6.1", "7", "7.1", "7.2", "8.1", "8.1A)", "8.1B)", "8.2"]

    # Make some fake data
    # Fixing random state for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(19680801)
    # Random data arrays the size of ex_y
    ex_x = list(np.random.randn(len(ex_y)))
    # Make a y-axis based on numbers so we can manipulate it later (ex_y we can use to set the y-tick labels later)
    numerical_y = list(np.arange(0, len(ex_y), 1))

    l_x = [0, 0]
    l_y = [47, 0]

    z_x = [-10, 10]
    z_y = [0, 0]

    # We can find when the line between two points crosses the x-axis
    for idx_point, x_point in enumerate(ex_x):
        # Skip the first value as we need 2 points for a line
        if idx_point == 0:
            continue
        # Get the x and y value of the point before so we can check if it corssed the x-axis
        x_point_before = ex_x[idx_point-1]
        y_point = numerical_y[idx_point]
        y_point_before = numerical_y[idx_point-1]
        # We are looking for when x goes from positive to negative and vice-versa
        if ((x_point < 0) == (x_point_before < 0)) == False:
            # If they are 0.0, we already introduced the 'fake' point so we can skip
            if x_point_before == 0.0 or x_point == 0.0:
                continue
            # The point before
            point_1 = (x_point_before, y_point_before)
            # The current point
            point_2 = (x_point, y_point)
            # Find y value
            y_intercept = find_y_intercept(point_1, point_2)
            # Insert new fake x and y points into our data
            numerical_y.insert(idx_point, y_intercept)
            ex_x.insert(idx_point, 0.0)

    # Create a set of line segments so that we can color them individually
    # This creates the points as a N x 1 x 2 array so that we can stack points
    # together easily to get the segments. The segments array for line collection
    # needs to be numlines x points per line x 2 (x and y)
    points = np.array([ex_x, numerical_y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

    # What color each line segment will be
    linecolors = []
    for line in segments:
        # Check what the combined x value of endpoints of the line would be
        value = line[0][0] + line[1][0]
        # if both endpoints are negative, then that line is red
        color_line = 'r' if value < 0 else 'g'
        linecolors.append(color_line)

    # Create the line collection object, setting the colormapping parameters.
    # Have to set the actual values used for colormapping separately.
    lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=linecolors)
    lc.set_array(ex_x)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(ex_y), 1))
    ax.set_yticklabels(ex_y)
    for x in range(-10, 10):
        plt.plot(l_x, l_y, color="k", linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(z_x, z_y, color='k', linewidth=1)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.title("Perfil Neuropsicológico")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    # Illustration
    x1, y1 = (-3, 4)
    x2, y2 = (6, 2)

    # Create fake point
    x_fake = 0
    y_fake = find_y_intercept((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
    ax[0].plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], label="line between point 1 and 2")
    ax[0].plot(x_fake, y_fake, 'o', color='orange', label="new 'fake' point")
    ax[0].plot(x1, y1, 'o', color='r', label="Point 1")
    ax[0].plot(x2, y2, 'o', color='g', label="Point 2")
    ax[0].axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=5, color='k', linewidth=0.5, ls='--')
    ax[0].legend()
    ax[0].set_ylabel('y')
    ax[0].set_xlabel('x')

    ax[1].plot([x1, x_fake], [y1, y_fake], color='r', label="line between point 1 and fake new point")
    ax[1].plot([x2, x_fake], [y2, y_fake], color='g', label="line between fake new point and point 2")
    ax[1].plot(x1, y1, 'o', color='r', label="Point 1")
    ax[1].plot(x2, y2, 'o', color='g', label="Point 2")
    ax[1].plot(x_fake, y_fake, 'o', color='orange', label="new 'fake' point")
    ax[1].axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=5, color='k', linewidth=1, ls='--')
    ax[1].legend()
    ax[1].set_ylabel('y')
    ax[1].set_xlabel('x')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

---

Just thought that if you wanted to include the original points in the graph, you could find where we put the zeros and eliminate them using `numpy.where` to find the zeros and `numpy.delete`.

```
ex_x_copy = np.array(ex_x)
zeros = np.where(ex_x_copy == 0.0)
original_ex_x = np.delete(ex_x_copy, zeros)
original_numerical_y = np.delete(numerical_y, zeros)
```

You couldn't just plot the original `ex_x` and `numerical_y` values because we added those 'fake' points so the indices would not match. Then just plot the new 'original' data with the updated indices:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(ex_y), 1))
    ax.plot(original_ex_x, original_numerical_y, 'o', color='k', markersize=2)
    ax.set_yticklabels(ex_y)
    for x in range(-10, 10):
        plt.plot(l_x, l_y, color="k", linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(z_x, z_y, color='k', linewidth=1)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.title("Perfil Neuropsicológico")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

[image: final figure with 'o' dots]